# Angular: page title service still get changes on navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, angular6

I am facing the issue on browser navigation buttons.
the scenario is like I have dynamic page title service that changes the browser title with routing.

When a user logs in the website and then log out. But now if the user press back button of the browser is able to see visited pages on the browser title bar.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-title',
  template: '<span></span>'
})
export class TitleComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private titleService: Title) {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(() => {
        let currentRoute = this.route.root;
        let title = '';
        do {
          const childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
          currentRoute = null;
          childrenRoutes.forEach(routes => {
            if (routes.outlet === 'primary') {
              title = routes.snapshot.data.title;
              currentRoute = routes;
            }
          });
        } while (currentRoute);
        if (title !== undefined ) {
          this.titleService.setTitle(title + ' | ParadiseXTrades');
        }
      });
  }
}
```

The above is my title service and the sample of routing is like,

```
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    data: {
      title: "Dashboard",
      icon: "icon-view-grid",
      caption: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
      status: true
    }
  }
```

Feel free to ask a question on comment regarding the question.

Comment: You need to unsubscribe the routing events.

Comment: can you guide how?

Comment: Nikhil Savaliya Did that work?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to unsubscribe to the routing subscription in  your TitleComponent, Update your TitleComponent to implement OnDestroy and inside that unsubscribe the subscription:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class TitleComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private routeSub: Subscription;
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private titleService: Title) {
         this.routeSub = this.router.events
         .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
         .subscribe(() => {
            let currentRoute = this.route.root;
            let title = '';
            do {
              const childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
              currentRoute = null;
              childrenRoutes.forEach(routes => {
                if (routes.outlet === 'primary') {
                  title = routes.snapshot.data.title;
                  currentRoute = routes;
                }
              });
            } while (currentRoute);
            if (title !== undefined ) {
              this.titleService.setTitle(title + ' | ParadiseXTrades');
            }
          });
      }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
      this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
    }
 }
```

Comment: its not working.
have to work with navigationEnd something

Comment: How are you using the TitleComponent .. Are you inserting it's selector in every component?

Comment: I understand that you are generating the title dynamically based on route.. but my questions is where do you listen for route changes... in each and  every component? Or just in TitleComponent and using TitleComponent in every component?

Comment: see the udpated question